# making fields validation at the same time

Tags: java

I have 3 fields (name, password, email). I want to check if they are valid or not. I wrote the following

```
 public boolean isValidInput() {
     if(name.isValid()){
         return false;
       }
      if(password.isInValid()){
         return false;
       }
       if(email.isInValid()){
         return false;
       }
      return true;
  }
```

so this will give me a single invalid. But what to do if I want to show the invalids all at the same time?

Comment: plz have a look at teh edited code

Comment: When you expect someone to take time for your question, then you should also take time to ask it properly. For example your edit: why is `name` still checked for being valid and not invalid like the others? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can handle this. But each of them need a change in the caller to handle these cases.

1. Create a custom exception which accepts a list of messages. Every time a validation failed add the error to the list, at the end of `isValidInput()` if the list is not empty then throw an exception with the list of errors.
2. Return the list of errors from above, instead of throwing exception.
3. Return a list of boolean variable and each index in the list will represent the status of a validation (name, email, etc)
4. Have an Enum of all fields that are present. Return a list of enum that failed. Empty list indicates that no error has occurred.

There are still a lot of other ways to handle this. It all depends on what suits you the best.
I would say, try some of them and see how it goes.

Comment: EnumSet should be prefered.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply return an integer from the function like this

```
 public int isValidInput() {
     if(name.isValid()){
         return 1;
       }
      if(password.isInValid()){
         return 2;
       }
       if(email.isInValid()){
         return 3;
       }
      return 0;
  }
```

and then check the integer to find out which one failed!

It would be better of course to define `static final` `int`s with the names of the errors to make the code more readable and robust.